# Javascript setting form attributes

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

```
Javascript code:

<script type="text/javascript">
   function submitForm() {
    alert("hhhhh");

//            document.forms[0].action ="http://navislink.apmtmumbai.com/express/lines/cnt_details.jsp";
//            document.forms[0].submit();
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{name: " + rashmi + " }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status) {

                console.log("CallWM");
                alert(data.d);
            },               
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });

    }

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response)
    document.forms[0].action =response;  //"http://navislink.apmtmumbai.com/express/lines/cnt_details.jsp";
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

webmethod

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
    {
        //return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        //+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
        DataTable dtContTrack = new DataTable();
        dtContTrack = Class1.GetRecord1("SELECT u_url FROM urltb WHERE u_id=(  SELECT max(u_id) FROM urltb  )");
        return dtContTrack.Rows[0]["u_url"].ToString();
    }
```

Here is my brief code,i want set some link to the form action.on button click submitForm() is executing,if hard code the code it will work;if i use in onsuccess method the url is not setting.Please help me to resolve.

Comment: from where you are getting response in `function OnSuccess(response)` is it the same as `data.d`

Comment: Are you returning URL string in data.d??.what is response in OnSuccess function?

Comment: ' return dtContTrack.Rows[0]["u_url"].ToString();'  on  `alert(response)` i am getting url, if i hard code directly after ` alert("hhhhh");`  it is working.

Comment: Hope the data: '{name: " + rashmi + " }' was not a copy-paste error. It should be data: '{name: "' + rashmi + '" }'

Comment: is this a `Hyperlink` or `innerLink`?
if it is a `Hyperlink` than it have to work well, but if it is a innerLink than we don't need to provide full link.
For Example : **HyperLink** `http://navislink.apmtmumbai.com/express/lines/cnt_details.jsp`
  **InnerLink** `/express/lines/cnt_details.jsp`
This may help You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work-->

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
var TestURL=response.replace(/"/g, '');
        alert(TestURL);
        document.forms[0].action =TestURL;
            document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

Replace the quotes around the URL string with blank spaces :)

Answer (score 1):

esponse is the object always. In order to to get your data you have to use response.d.

Source:-  http://encosia.com/2009/06/29/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

> “.d” what? If you aren’t familiar with the “.d” I’m referring to, it
>   is simply a security feature that Microsoft added in ASP.NET 3.5’s
>   version of ASP.NET AJAX. By encapsulating the JSON response within a
>   parent object, the framework helps protect against a particularly
>   nasty XSS vulnerability.

You need to write `response.d` as below :-

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d)
    document.forms[0].action =response.d;  //"http://navislink.apmtmumbai.com/express/lines/cnt_details.jsp";
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: author is able to fetch URL in response.So no need to make it response.d